# Why isn't push() valid?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on editing a json file in Node.JS, but I'm stuck on this part:

```
 var filterlist = require('./censor.json');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var addWord = req.body.addBlacklist;
        addWord = addWord.trim();
        addWord = addWord.toLowerCase();
        var findWord = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < filterlist.Words.length; i++) {
            if(filterlist.Words[i] == addWord) {
                findWord = true;
            }
        }
        if(findWord == false) {
            filterlist.Words.push(addWord);
            ...
```

Even though push() IS a function, all I get back is

`TypeError: filterlist.Words.push is not a function`

EDIT: Here's the JSON.

`{"Words":{},"Phrases":{},"Whitelist":{}}`

And I have no idea why. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `type(filterlist.Words)`?

Comment: It is `[object Array]`. I just checked it. I guess the way he's parsing JSON might be a problem. Check here http://jsbin.com/yulidinidi/edit?js,console

Comment: if `filterlist.Words.push is not a function` then it's very likely that `filterlist.Words` is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `{"Words":{}`
to `{"Words":[]`, and update the other entries of your json if needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"Words":{},"Phrases":{},"Whitelist":{}}
```

With this JSON Words will be parsed as an object, not an array. As proposed, change it to:

```
{"Words":[],"Phrases":{},"Whitelist":{}}
```